# Why is a comment on a question "on hold" missing?

Tags: support

Re. the question: "What kind of rectifier circuit would I need to build a 25-30V 3A power supply with an input voltage of 24V AC?" which was recently put on hold, I posted a comment requesting that the question be taken off hold, and I provided a couple of reasons why I believed the question was valid.

Subsequently, my comment has vanished.

Clue, please?

Comment: Could you post a link to that thread?  So far, I found only [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145509/rectifier-for-3a-load).  But I don't see any of your comments have been deleted there.  Maybe, I'm looking at a wrong thread.

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong title/subject; it's "Rectifier for 3A load [on hold]"

Comment: (1) I was asking for a link.  If you post a link, that removes any uncertainties associated with me having to search for the thread.  (2) Again, I don't see any comments of yours which have been deleted in that thread.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to find the link you're asking for. Clue, please?

Comment: It's just the link for the question you're talking about. Just copy it from your browser.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The thread in question is this: [Rectifier for 3A load](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145509/rectifier-for-3a-load).

I don't see any deleted comments by EM Fields in that thread.  When a comment is deleted, it doesn't completely disappear.  It remains visible to moderators.

Comment: OK, thanks for your time.  I guess I'll just repost it and see what happens...  Tomorrow...

Comment: It's tomorrow, and I've decided to let it go.

Comment: Maybe you typed the comment, but the browser was closed or you went to a different page before actually submitting the comment?  I remember doing this a few times accidentally when I was new to the site.